# For how long can I follow up on a position without being annoying?

Tags: follow-up, covid-19

It's been more than a month since I applied to a position in this COVID-era, I've been persistent in my follow-ups with HR (waiting at least one week before sending a reminder), and I've still not received any confirmation of the position, apart from a few questions including [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/169366/how-to-answer-the-question-do-you-have-any-relatives-working-with-us). My application status has always been **Under Review**.

I've been following up with only one particular person (which is why I believe I may come off as annoying) and my communication mediums have always been emails, and calls to initiate a quick response.

Assuming that nobody is obligated to respond to my request, for how long is it ethical for me to keep following up on this position?

Comment: Apply somewhere else. If they don’t have the manners to reply appropiately then they won’t respond in a timely fashion for other requests...

Comment: @SolarMike It is a a large reputable firm

Comment: Why are you worrying about being annoying? It's only once a week.

Comment: What has being "a large reputable firm" have to do with anything?

Comment: @jcm Don't large businesses have a well defined HR Department?

Comment: @Luke sure, but SolarMike was talking about timeliness and appropriate behaviour, not having an HR Department. Those don't necessarily go hand-in-hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just keep on doing what you're doing.

This has, incidentally, nothing to do with ethics. It's really a question of "what do you want" and then "how do you get it".

Presumably you want this job, and pushing for it is how you get it. Look, nobody ever got dinged from a job *because they wanted it too much*. you ding ppl for not wanting the job enough!

Its once a week, whoever you're emailing can survive that. Just make sure you're not putting all your hopes in this one thing - keep your own job search going. But really, I don't see any problem with trying to get a job.

Comment: I like this answer but want to also add that it is a great idea to send a "I'm still interested" email. Just say you want the job and wish to hear back from them. Also see if they have other positions open and perhaps the person will remember you enough to get you first place for an interview or consideration.

Comment: This answer definitely resonates with my thinking

Answer (score 1):

One follow up email is enough.

As you have correctly surmised, persistent follow up correspondence will just get you labeled as annoying.

Comment: Any reason as to why just one is enough?

Comment: It's an Internship Position and I guess it can be classified as an unsolicited application